# Is there some way to autogenerate database tables that makes use MembershipProvider and role provider?

Tags: c#, database, asp.net-membership, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to start a new application from scratch. First thing I want to start with is user authentication. Using membership provider makes things much easier to register and authenticate user, but how do I setup my database so that MembershipProvider and RoleProvider can be used? Is there some smart way to generate tables in database so that MembershipProvider can be used? Can someone provide any tutorials or suggestion on what should I do to set things up to make use of Membership and RoleProvider? Obviously, it should be able to expand database in future.

Comment: check `http://support.discountasp.net/KB/a337/how-to-configure-aspnet-membershiproles-provider-to.aspx`

Comment: I suggest looking into Entity Framework.  It will generate tables and with Data Migrations it will also change the tables as time goes on.

Answer (score 0):

Think this will help you

[Creating the Membership Schema in SQL Server](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/security/membership/creating-the-membership-schema-in-sql-server-cs)